# Angular 7: Get locale thousand Separator and decimal Marker characters

Tags: angular7, locale

I've seen solutions where people are writing out amounts with `formatCurrency(1234.56, this.locale, '')` and then extracting the characters from the produced string.

Please Google ... tell me this is not the only way.

Answer (score 1):

- thousand Separator:

  `getLocaleNumberSymbol(this.locale, NumberSymbol.CurrencyGroup)`
- decimal marker:

  `getLocaleNumberSymbol(this.locale, NumberSymbol.CurrencyDecimal)`